# Storing data from cloud page to salesforce using Rest API

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, marketingcloudapi

We want to fetch the data from the cloud page and instead of storing that in a data extension we want to store that in salesforce but we don't want to use marketing cloud connect.
Is it possible to do using Rest API and how?

Comment: Do you like to write the data from the CloudPage code to Salesforce CRM or do you like to fetch it from Salesforce CRM code from a Data Extension?

Comment: Hi Markus, I want to write the data from the CloudPage code to Salesforce CRM

Answer (score 2):

In order to interact with / write to Salesforce CRM from CloudPages without using Marketing Cloud Connect, you can access the Salesforce CRM REST-API.
The easiest way to do so is by using the Marketing Cloud Language "Server-Side JavaScript", as you can make use of javascript objects to natively interact using JSON-format.

However, the default functions are limited to GET and POST calls that only let you create a record or retrieve data from it.
In order to be able to update, delete, etc. you need to use `Script.Util.HttpRequest` and create your own requests, that suit your needs:

**Approximate example code for an update:**

```html
<script runat=server>
    var req = new Script.Util.HttpRequest("https://yourInstance.salesforce.com/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/Account/yourid");
    req.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer YOURTOKEN");
    req.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    req.method = "PATCH";
    req.postData = Stringify({
        "BillingCity" : "San Francisco"
    });

    var resp = req.send();
</script>
```

**Related documentation:**

- [Salesforce CRM REST-API Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_what_is_rest_api.htm)
- [REST-API - Working with Records](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/using_resources_working_with_records.htm)
- [Server-Side JavaScript Syntax Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_syntaxGuide.htm)
- [SSJS Post function](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_httpPost.htm)
- [SSJS Script.Util.HttpRequest documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformContentSyndicationScriptUtilHttpRequest.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can create `Schedulable` apex class which runs every 1 hour(you can change interval as per your requirment). Create a `Batch` apex class and call from Schedulable class where it will make callout and you will get the response. Process the response you got from callout and insert the records using DML statement in batch. Keep the batch size as 100 as you know we can make only 100 callout per transaction.